# Redirect all HTTP-Requests with *.asp to one single file

Tags: iis, asp-classic, coldfusion, http-redirect

Is it possible on an IIS to redirect all files with the file extension .asp to one single file (i.e. switch.php, switch.cfm) and how?
Thx in advance for the upcoming solutions :)

EDIT:
version of IIS is "IIS 6.0"

Comment: Can you tell us which version of IIS - will help the people answering to give you detailed steps.

Comment: Thx for your comment. Added the version in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a few different thoughts off the top of my head:

1. Use an ISAPI filter. Either write your own or use a commercial one like [Helicon ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) (the reverse proxy feature should be able to do this).
2. Add a global.asa file to the root of the site and Response.Redirect to the page you want in the Session_OnStart event (I think this event still fires if the requested page doesn’t actually exist but am not 100% sure). More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_globalasa.asp).
3. Define a new 404 “File not found” page in IIS which loads a custom page with a redirect to your desired URL. You could do this with either client or server side script and make it conditional on the requested URL having a .asp extension so as not to catch genuine 404s for other file types.

I’d say option 1 is your “best practice” approach but option 3 would get you up and running very quickly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

your going to want to look into "iis modrewrite" on google :)

lets you use regular expressions to define rules and you can set a global match to rewrite to 1 page